# How can I code for calculating a CompilationUnit lines of code in

Tags: eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I would like to calcualate a compilation unit lines of code intuitively. How can I use the method of CompilationUnit: CompilationUnit.getLineNumber([THELASTLINE].getPosition()) to get the lines of code of this compilationUnit. How can I get the ast node which contains "the last line" then?

Many thanks,

Comment: By `line of code` do you mean **Physical Lines of Code** or **Logical line of code** or both?

Comment: @Favonius, Hi Thanks, I eventually got the answer. `code` Document doc = new Document(myComilationUnit.getSource()); Integer loc = doc.getNumberOfLines(); `code`